# Saving image to a folder in IIS localhost

Tags: c#, .net, iis, localhost, image-uploading

I have to save images to a folder located in "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\" and named as "UploadedImages". Here is my code:

```
         public string SaveImage(string base64,int compno)
{
    string res = "";
    try
    {

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(base64)))
        {
            using (Bitmap bm2 = new Bitmap(ms))
            {
                bm2.Save(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedImages/ID"+compno+".jpg"));
            }
        }
        res = "done";
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        res = ex.ToString();
    }
    return res;
}
```

but it throws "A generic error occured in GDI+ at System.Drawing.Image.Save" exception. What am I doing wrong? This code works fine when saving image locally as

```
       bm2.Save("D:Embasy\UploadedImages\ID"+compno+".jpg"));
```

What changes do I need to make to save images in localhost directory?

Comment: Check if this is of help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438194/gdi-error-when-uploading-images-to-server-but-not-localhost?rq=1

Comment: no it didnt help me because I am not using any goDAddy account and don't even know what is it

Comment: It is not about godaddy (An internet service provider) but about the System.Drawing classes.

Answer (score 0):

Your not going to believe this -- the site running v1.1 had a virtual directory set-up which was mapped to the directory in which the image was saved to -- things worked fine.

The v2.0 site also had the same virtual directory name, but the physical path was different -- I changed the path to point to the same directory as the v1.0 site and now the code works.

So in short -- you were right about the "path must exist".

**Classes within the System.Drawing namespace are not supported for use within a Windows or ASP.NET service. Attempting to use these classes from within one of these application types may produce unexpected problems, such as diminished service performance and run-time exceptions. For a supported alternative, see Windows Imaging Components.**

and kindly refer this link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xs6ftd89.aspx

Comment: so I cant use it in service but can I use this method in web page of my website? i mean using  aspx page? This method did save image on my local disk "D" without any problem. Is that different?

Comment: Yes you can save. please refer my answer for d:

Answer (score 0):

When you are using **Server.Mappath**

```
bm2.Save(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedImages/ID"+compno+".jpg"));
```

**"~(tield)"** : is point to project/application root folder **c:\inetpub\wwwroot\yourproject**

then find remaining your path /UploadedImages and then create ID1.jpg.

But  your imagefolder  "UploadImages" is exist in d: **not in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\yourproject**

> if you want to exist your image folder in D: then you should to **create
>   virtual directory** and then you need to apply path as relevant

Comment: no my folder is present in "C". I created another folder with the same name in "D" to check this code bm2.Save("D:Embasy\UploadedImages\ID"+compno+".jpg"));

Answer (score 0):

My problem actually was that every time i published website, I replaced the "UploadedImages" folder too and thus permissions were changed. So, i didnt replaced the folder again after changing its permissions and creating "everyone" group and giving full rights to it. Now code is working perfectly :)